# grub error "superfluous RAID member" on update-grub

Tags: debian, grub2, mdadm

My system (wheezy/sid: 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux) is running fine - I'm just wondering what some messages mean.
I have two mdraid arrays running up on my system. Here's `cat /proc/mdstat`:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sda3[0] sdc3[3] sdb3[1]
      823103488 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]

md0 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdc2[2](S) sdb2[1]
      72628769 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

I use `/dev/md0` as `/` and `/dev/md1` as `/home`.
Whenever `update-grup` is running - or while grub comes up, I receive the error:
`error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).`.

To understand why I'd like to remove this, have a look at the result of `update-grub`:

```
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
Generating grub.cfg ...
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-amd64
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found).
  No volume groups found
done
```

How can I get rid of these messages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=610184) on the update-grub script. After what is said in the Debian bug report, a patch has been applied upstream so it should be fixed in the Debian package at some time.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I haven't found these details using `our friends from google`.